# How to do distributed metrics on Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

today I get requirements to apply metrics on our Spring boot app using Prometheus, Grafana, Actuator.

Here is the detail:

- Count the number of HTTP input of a HTTP API endpoint
- Count the number of HTTP output of a HTTP API endpoint
- Get latency of a HTTP API endpoint processing
- And the last, get latency of a end to end flow (mean that when user hit the API endpoint, then it invoke another microservice by kafka, then go to next microservice blabla, and the latency is total time it took)

I think first 3 requirement can be archived easily:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then:

```
Metrics.counter(name, tags).increment();
Metrics.timer(name, tags).record(duration.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But the last requirement is so difficult to me. I don't have any idea how to collect metrics across microservice.

Please give me some possible and acceptable solution. Thanks very much.

Comment: Prometheus is not really about traceability. If you want trace something like you described, and your in- and out- points are different, your best shot would be to pass either timestamp of start or duration of previous steps as additional parameters with your data, and create metrics at the last step.

Comment: If your flow is asynchronous, you need to customize monitoring flows. You can use a TrckerId in the request and then use it to collect latency asynchronous service metrics.

Comment: @zohreh what does TrckerId come from? I mean whether it come from another library like spring-cloud-sleuth or not

Comment: No, you have to define it. For example, you can create a UUID for each request and put it as a specific value in the metric report, and then aggregate it.

Comment: @zohreh could you provide me some lines of example code? I'm new to metrics/tracing so that i'm not sure about "aggregate it"

Comment: Yes, sure. Please message my LinkedIn account for better communication. 
linkedin.com/in/zohreh-batouei-713761a

Answer (score 0):

To measure the latency of an end-to-end flow involving multiple services in method X, you can define custom metrics using the **@Timed** annotation. Here's an optimized version of your answer:

```
@Timed(METRIC_NAME)
public Response methodX() {
// Service call 1
// ...
// Service call n
// Perform the necessary operations

return response;
}
```

By annotating the **methodX()** with **@Timed** and providing a custom metric name (**METRIC_NAME**), you can capture the duration of the method execution. This allows you to measure the end-to-end latency of the flow.

Make sure you have the necessary dependencies and configuration in place to enable metric collection, such as using Micrometer with Prometheus and Spring Boot Actuator.

Remember to adjust the metric name (**METRIC_NAME**) to something that reflects the purpose and context of the measured operation.

With this optimization, you can easily track the performance of the end-to-end flow and gain insights into the latency of each service call within the method.

Comment: Cannot use this. The flow is async and never comeback